# Making Partial View Reusable

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, partial-views

Say I have a partial view that renders a dropdown list of Applications. When selecting an item in the dropdown it renders another partial view.

This dropdown list exists in a few places in the application but on each page a different partial view needs to be rendered when selecting an application. Is there an easy way to make the dropdown reusable? ie I need to set a different data_url depending on which page the partial view is rendered.

Partial View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $('#ApplicationsDropdownList').change(function () {
            var url = $(this).data('url');
            var applicationId = $(this).val();
            $('#RolesForApplication').load(url, { applicationId: applicationId})
        });
    });

</script>

<div>

<label for='ApplicationsDropdownList'>Application:</label>

 @Html.DropDownListFor(
        x => x.SelectedApplicationId, 
        new SelectList(Model.Applications, "Value", "Text"),
        "-- Select Application --",
             new
             {
                 id = "ApplicationsDropdownList",
                 data_url = Url.Action("ViewRolesTableForApplication", "Index")
             }
    )   
</div>
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult ViewRolesTableForApplication(string applicationId)
        {
...
 return View("_RolesTableForApplicationPartial");
        }
```

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but why can't you just make a string containing your data_url be another part of the Model for your partial view?

Comment: @AFinkelstein I dont think you are misunderstanding...I think that might be the simple and very obvious answer I was looking for

Comment: Haha, glad I could help. I'll make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a string property containing the data_url to the model that you use for your partial view.

So in addition to the Model containing `Applications` it will have `public string DataUrl { get; set; }` as well.